# Echo table in php and result in php

Tags: php

i doing a live search, it work fine, the problem is that i not able to echo it in a format that i want, can someone help please,

```
  while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($q))
     {
    $title = $r["Title"];
    $profile = $r["Tag"];

    echo '<div class="result"><table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Title</th>
                  <th>Year</th>
                  <th>Cast</th>
                  <th>Tags</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>        
              <?php

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM movie ORDER BY MovieID DESC';
                 $r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $sql);
                 while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
                        echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td>'. $row['Title'] . '</td>';
                        echo '<td>'. $row['YEAR'] . '</td>';
                        echo '<td>'. $row['Cast'] . '</td>';
                        echo '<td>'. $row['Tag'] . '</td>';
                        echo '<td width=250>';
                        echo '<a class="btn" href="read.php?id='.$row['MovieID'].'">View</a>';
                        echo ' ';
                        echo '<a class="btn btn-success" href="update.php?id='.$row['MovieID'].'">Edit</a>';
                        echo ' ';
                        echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="delete.php?id='.$row['MovieID'].'">Delete</a>';
                        echo '</td>';
                        echo '</tr>';
               }

              ?>
              </tbody>
          </table>






              </div>';
```

Could someone help, because it not displaying my result please

Comment: You dont see any result at all? what error do you get

Comment: @media He's writing PHP code in the middle of his html-string. It's pretty evident what errors follows after `$str = 'some stuff'SELECT....`.

Comment: @meda, it is printing the html code not the result but when i remove the html code, it print the result

Comment: @ccKep yeah its messy in the middle, sometime people make copy paste typos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to close the single quote after first echo like. try this

```
<?php
  while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($q))
     {
    $title = $r["Title"];
    $profile = $r["Tag"];

    echo '<div class="result"><table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Title</th>
                  <th>Year</th>
                  <th>Cast</th>
                  <th>Tags</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>';      


    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM movie ORDER BY MovieID DESC';
                 $r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $sql);
                 while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
                        echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td>'. $row['Title'] . '</td>';
                        echo '<td>'. $row['YEAR'] . '</td>';
                        echo '<td>'. $row['Cast'] . '</td>';
                        echo '<td>'. $row['Tag'] . '</td>';
                        echo '<td width=250>';
                        echo '<a class="btn" href="read.php?id='.$row['MovieID'].'">View</a>';
                        echo ' ';
                        echo '<a class="btn btn-success" href="update.php?id='.$row['MovieID'].'">Edit</a>';
                        echo ' ';
                        echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="delete.php?id='.$row['MovieID'].'">Delete</a>';
                        echo '</td>';
                        echo '</tr>';
               }


        echo
        '</tbody>
          </table>
       </div>';
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all:
Why are you using a `<?php` in your first echo?

Replace it with an closing `';` and everything should work fine.